# Propel - check if column is autoincrement

Tags: php, sql, oop, orm, propel

Is there a way in `propel2` to check if the column is `autoincrement` ? My assumption would be to use something similar to

```
$query = new UsersQuery();

$columns = $query->getTableMap()->getColumns();

foreach ($columns as $column) {
    $column->isAutoIncrement(); //method does not exist
}
```

However, nothing that would actually check if the column is `autoincrement` does not exist when iterating over the result of `getColumns`. What could be done in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The default value `AUTO_INCREMENT` is driver specific. You cannot expect a method dedicated for this. It could be `AUTOINCREMENT` in MySQL, `SEQUENCE` in PostgreSQL, etc...

The thing I do suggest is to find the primary key, as I expect that you do search this column.

Another workaround is to take the CREATE TABLE code from the migrations and parse it manually. But there is no built-in method for this. Even if you execute `getDefaultValue()` you will not recieve `AUTO_INCREMENT`, but `NULL` for that column.